# How to run non-web docker container on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

What I have are Python Scripts that listen to SQS and Process messages received from those.These are dockerized and uploaded to ECR. What the requirement is to run this docker on ECS using EC2 and Scale up/in based on the number of messages from sqs.

The issue is I am not able to run the tasks defined, I think the reason for it is the health check is not set, so I set it to CMD_SHELL, ps aux | grep "Python" || exit 1 , but of no use can anyone help me with it. Also is it possible to run Non-Web application on ECS.

If anyone has any documents please point me put to it.

I am posting my container definition here

```
i-00bd43d507b521acc



{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "python-extract",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "/tmp/bin/main"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 256,
      "environment": [
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 512,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "<docker-registery:latest>",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": {
        "retries": 3,
        "command": [
          "ps aux | grep "python" || exit 1"
        ],
        "timeout": 5,
        "interval": 30,
        "startPeriod": 5
      },
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "python-extract"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "1024",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<is>:role/ecsTaskRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "<ecsTaskRole>",
  "family": "map-extractor",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 6,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Any suggestion on whether it's possible to run non-server containers on ECS would be of great help or any one has done it please let me know what should be the healtchecks

Answer (score 0):

"healthCheck" is not required for running ECS task. I would recommend you to check the stop status of the task and viewing the logs of the task in the "python-extract" CloudWatch log group.